# mysterious Python Pandas lambda function error

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a pandas dataframe and I have a column called 'email'.  I have verified the dtype is object.  It contains normally formatted emails such as xxx@yyy.com

When I do this:

```
$ df['emaillower'] = df['email'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-153-e951d53133eb>", line 1, in <module>
df['emaillower'] = df['email'].apply(lambda x: x.upper())

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", 
line 
2355, in apply
mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

File "pandas\_libs\src\inference.pyx", line 1569, in 
pandas._libs.lib.map_infer (pandas\_libs\lib.c:66440)

File "<ipython-input-153-e951d53133eb>", line 1, in <lambda>
df['emaillower'] = df['email'].apply(lambda x: x.upper())

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

What is going on?

Comment: does your "Email" columns contain only string??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the entries in the column 'email' is a float, not a string, and it doesn't know how to do upper() on a float. This is common when one entry is empty and is converted to NaN - this is read as a float and that's the source of your error. Something like this may fix the problem:

```
df['emaillower'] = df['email'].apply(lambda x: x.upper() if type(x) is str else 'empty')
```

Also want to note that you call the column emaillower but you are actually making it upper case - this might cause some confusion in the future

Comment: The situation is funny because the SQL that generated the input file for the dataframe load specified that email > ' '      So all my email values are populated... nevertheless Python complained about float.  I just did df['email'] = df['email'].astype(str)

Comment: for clarity i corrected the original question so the field name emaillower matched the lower() function

Answer (score 2):

Will suggest using [str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.upper.html#pandas.Series.str.upper) function from pandas

```
df['emaillower'] = df['email'].astype(np.str).str.upper()
```

I have used astye(np.str) to be sure all values are converted to string .

Comment: Thanks these comments suggested to me that I put in:   df['email'] = df['email'].astype(str)  and that fixed the issue.   When I eyeballed the data, it looked all proper in the form xxxx@yyyy.com  but clearly somewhere Python interpreted something as a float.

Comment: @MarkGinsburg, please consider upvoting this answer if it gives you any help